# Install only Firebase Auth from the Firebase-Admin SDK (Python)

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

`firebase-admin` python package is 100MB.
I am only using it to verify `idToken` server-side in HTTP requests.
This means i am using only 1 method of this package.

I would like to remove the `Firestore` and the `Cloud Storage` dependencies from the package to reduce the size if possible.

Can I simply install the `firebase_admin.auth` package with only its dependencies with a `pip install firebase-admin --only auth` looking-like command ?

If not, how can i filter easily the packages inside to only keep the needed for `firebase_admin.auth` module ? (=not spending time to understand manually all of the dependencies for each required file)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any third party library like [PyJWT](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead of using Firebase Admin SDK to decode Firebase ID Tokens if you need it for verifying tokens only.

Once the token is decoded you can verify the headers and constraints mentioned in [Verify ID Tokens using third party JWT library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) section of the documentation:

> Finally, ensure that the ID token was signed by the private key corresponding to the token's `kid` claim. Grab the public key from https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com and use a JWT library to verify the signature. Use the value of `max-age` in the `Cache-Control` header of the response from that endpoint to know when to refresh the public keys.